# not login properly in facebook in my application

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using facebook login through javascript SDK (fb.login). and when i was login through, sometimes it works properly but sometimes it continuously asking for email and password.

for example, i have enter email id and pwd in this window:

[image]

after that it continuously asking for email and password.

i have included this:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <img src="<?= $this->baseUrl(); ?>/public/images/facebook_signup.jpg" onclick="fb_login();"/>
    <script>
    FB.init({appId: '061665c433986c406bbeda1b465350c1', status: true,
        cookie: true, xfbml: true});

    function fb_login()
    {
        FB.login(function(response)
            {
                if(response.session!=null)
                {
                    window.location.href="http://www.allindiaarchitects.com/registration";
                }
                },{perms:'email,user_birthday,offline_access,publish_stream,read_friendlists'});
    }

    </script>
```

Please anybody help me.

Comment: Provide your code that you are using for login

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div id="fb-root">
    <img src="<?= $this->baseUrl(); ?>/public/images/facebook_signup.jpg" onclick="fb_login();"/>
</div>
```

If it doesn't work, try this:

```
<div id="fb-root">
    <fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" size="medium" background="white" length="short"></fb:login-button>
</div>
```